# Rails Event EventType model association - undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, belongs-to

I have a problem with listing EventType title from Event-EventType model association.

In this case, I have a simple Event model and EventType model.
Event model has field eventtype_id.

Now when I want to show EventType Title I am getting error `'undefined method`title' for nil:NilClass'`

I tried with `belongs_to` and `has_many` associations but not work. Probably I am doing something wrong.

[image: Event Model:]

[image: Event Type Model:]

[image: Show EventType.Title problem]
[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

If your model is `EventType`, then your foreign key should be `event_type_id`

To go on with your structure you can try to customize `belongs_to` with parameter `foreign_key: :eventtype_id`, but it's a hack.

On the other hand you should get errors about your associations and it's not clear for me why don't you have it.

If that's not working for you, then provide call please your target object in `rails c` (rails console), show it's attributes and double check that you really have `EventType` with id from `Event` calling `EventType.find([yout_event_id])`

Comment: Write please whether that helped or not?

Comment: Hi Anton,  thank you for your response.  I tried even with foreign keys I got some results but insted of getting eventtype.title I am getting event.title.  However, I find solution with : td = EventType.find(item.eventtype_id).title  in this case without any association I am getting eventtype title.

Comment: It's still a hack. Going such way you will turn into not using associations at all. As I asked, can you please provide me data from your target event object? Just paste console output for it

Comment: irb(main):001:0> EventType.find(1)
  EventType Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "event_types".* FROM "event_types" WHERE "event_types"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<EventType id: 1, title: "kafu", active: true, created_at: "2017-11-13 22:03:47", updated_at: "2017-11-13 22:03:47", image_file_name: "coffee.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 6327, image_updated_at: "2017-11-13 22:03:47">

Comment: irb(main):002:0> Event.all
  Event Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "events".* FROM "events" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 6, title: "Hajmo ba na ", place_id: 2, icon: nil, points: nil, public: true, user_id: 1, active: true, created_at: "2017-11-16 11:09:07", updated_at: "2017-11-16 11:09:07", event_date: "2017-11-16 23:59:00", eventtype_id: 1>]>

Comment: Can you check `Event.first.event_type.title` in console?

Comment: @AntonThachov  at the end I created new model caller etype and it is the same as eventtype model and it works well,   Not sure why but eventtype at event model was referenced like event_type_id and this new is like etype_id that  was only change and it works. Maybe something with model with two word in name EventType  or so... really not sure what caused problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
belongs_to :event_type, foreign_key: :eventtype_id, class_name: "EventType"
```

Or

You can rename your attribute by writing a migration

```
class EditField < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    rename_column :table_name, :old_column, :new_column
  end

  def down
    rename_column :table_name, :new_column, :old_column
  end
end
```

And then run rake db:migrate